# No hover feedback in OS X Yosemite

Tags: mouse, macos

I recently upgraded to OS X Yosemite. Everything works fine but for some odd reason my cursor fails to highlight (provide feedback on anything I hover on any options).

As an example (if I'm not explaining this very well):

[image]

When I hover over the options in the Safari menu (or any other menu, nothing shows up as a blue background as you would expect (it only turns blue after I've clicked it).

I've been running Mavericks for a long while, and I had no issues.

I'm not sure if the mouse has a part to play, I'm using Mad Catz R.A.T3, anyone know if this as an issue with Yosemite? Or are aware of a fix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue with my Mad Catz MMO 7 and I fixed the problem! If you download the latest driver software from http://madcatz.com/downloads/ for Mavericks (OS X 10.9) it fixes the problem. You will have to restart your computer in the process.

Comment: Ah, I downloading the drivers, I forgot to restart.  As soon as I did restart, the problem was resolved, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I reached out to MadCatz support and they have a workaround to get the Mavericks drivers working in Yosemite:

> Go to System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Unlock to
>   make changes
>
> In the list "Allow the apps below to control your computer" ticked the
>   following:
>
> - MadCatzSmartTechnology
> - Mad Catz Editor”

Answer (score 3):

For me the same with a Logitech MX connected to a unifying receiver. I did repair the mouse with the Unifying software provided by Logitech and then it worked again.

Comment: I've been fighting my mouse for 2 days, and this fixed it.  To anyone else, by "repair" he means to unpair and pair again.

Comment: I ran into this issue when I had the Unifying receiver connected in addition to a wired mouse. Unplugging the receiver, then unplugging my wired mouse and plugging it back in, fixed this.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with Mad Catz R.A.T. 5. I haven't tried to fix it yet, but it appears that the driver is the cause of the problems.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, my mouse isn't compatible with the Macbook Air A1466...I'm using a Logitech M510. For the longest time, it worked flawlessy with my 2011 Macbook Pro. Switched my computer yesterday for work, and a large part of it's functionality ceased to work. Including the hover option.

Comment: Could you add what drivers if any you use with the mentioned mice? It seems a pointer is t just a pointer for hover functionality ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem now in El Capitan with a RAT 3, and none of the above advice worked for me. I emailed their support and received the following reply (very quickly, to their credit):

> Thank you for contacting the MadCatz Tech Support Team.
>
> Please be advised that our developers are still working on a software for the most recent versions of the Mac operating systems.
>
> Unfortunately, we cannot provide you with a time frame when this will be available.
>
> What we can suggest is to use the device as a plug and play one or to ask for a refund if you have recently purchased it.
>
> I am sorry I cannot assist you with this.

I guess I'll just put up with it and hope that a fix happens sometime. I'll comment here if I do get more information.

Answer (score 0):

For me uninstall and install lastest Mad Catz RAT Driver 1.1.69 nothing changed. But when I delete MadCatz from Application and every file with name contain 'madcatz' from my drive and restart computer - hover function with my R.A.T. 9 work again. But sadly every time when I unplug my MacBook from Display problem appears again. When plug in Thunderbolt Display again to MacBook I must restart system.