# El Capitan incompatible with Mad Catz Editor

Tags: mouse, macos

I upgraded my Macbook Pro to OSX 10.11 El Capitan but sadly the mapping software for my Mad Catz Mouse (M.M.O.7) does not start anymore.

[Crash Report](http://pastebin.com/QuZHiEwr)

```
Process:               editor [33209]
Path:                  /Applications/Mad Catz Editor.app/Contents/MacOS/editor
Identifier:            com.madcatz.MadCatz.editor
Version:               1.0 (1.1.69)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           editor [33209]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-10-07 13:41:42.846 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11 (15A284)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        8B5B6605-7448-4DDA-627C-11145BEF80FE

Sleep/Wake UUID:       4D337680-5145-4CF7-B785-93E78B39BE4D

Time Awake Since Boot: 100000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       17000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MCProfile profile]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10042c350'
abort() called
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b3a7bd2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff866ac4fa objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b4110ed -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b3183d1 ___forwarding___ + 1009
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b317f58 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   MCDeviceLib.dylib                   0x0000000100041587 -[MCProfile checkName] + 119
```

The result is that I have a lot of hovering problem (hover event does not fire anymore) and shortcuts macros do not work at all.

Does anyone have a workaround ?

I contacted the Mad Catz team via Facebook and Twitter 2 days ago and I still have no answer.

Comment: Please put all info on this site and not pastebin

Comment: @Mark : I would love to but output is too large. Why does it bother you that it is on pastebin?

Comment: The referenced content on pastern.com might disappear, also it forces people to go through an extra hop just to understand the problem. That's why it is preferable to have questions/answers stand on their own.

Comment: sorry can't comment but it's re above workaround.
Firstly it's called USB Overdrive and is a paid software, the instruction is confusing when the installation is optional ;)
Controller mate is again another 3rd party software which I'm not familiar with. I gave Overdrive a try but didn't work for me as the status doesn't show the RAT 7 (but my apple keyboard).
I have currently uninstalled madcatz editor and navigate dashboard and mission control with keyboard and shortcuts.
The only thing which is not properly working is mouse hover over links. I rather wait for madcatz then messing up the sys

Comment: I'm sorry @XavierHaniquaut I cannot answer because of my reputation but I had the same and I was able to solve it, deleting the folder ~/Library/Application\ Support/Smart\ Technology.
Open your terminal and digit `sudo rm -R ~/Library/Application\ Support/Smart\ Technology` then open the editor again

Comment: @Serluca : Thanks that is a bit nicer, I managed to reopen the editor, but its not really stable. And I lost my previous config. I edited my post to show your answer.

Comment: @XavierHaniquaut I contacted them as well, seems that they are working on a new version

Comment: Please do not edit the question to include (partial) answers.

Comment: @serluca Can you post this as an answer please? There is no reputation requirement regarding answers, so unless you are blocked from answering in general answering should be possible.

Comment: @patrix 10 points required to answer this question, this is my first day and I'm not allowed to do it. Sorry

Comment: @serluca you have 101 reputation

Comment: @patrix I know, but is not my fault, look http://cl.ly/image/322w3b3p462T nothing that I can do...

Comment: Contacted them before Christmas and they said (quoting literally): "Please, be informed that we are working on a new software version that is 10.11 version. Still nothing. 

He hope to release it in the first part of 2016."

Comment: As of 2/10/16 they are still working on it but no date has been given for its completion.

Comment: If anyone is looking for mouse-over feedback on El Capitan, then see this answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/151439/64004  Installing the drivers of Mavericks on El Capitan works as advertised ... I have not tested any other features.  I used `Mad Catz RAT Driver 1.1.69.zip` and had it stored somewhere just in case I ever needed it ... I did not see it currently on the download site and am unsure if it is still available ....

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same issue, in a chat with Madcatz support they stated to come up with a new driver by end of this year - still a bit to suffer unfortunately.

Installing [USB overdrive and controller mate](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/211956/5472) are too much for me to achieve a little bump in functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the new security implemented in El Capitan (see [here](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2015/10/01/system-integrity-protection-adding-another-layer-to-apples-security-model/)), and if Mad Katz installs stuff in protected directories (such as `/usr/bin`), chances are the upgrade hosed the mouse.  Look in

`/Library/SystemMigration/History/Migration-something-about-your-computer/QuarantineRoot`

and see if there is anything about the mouse.  This is likely, especially if the mouse required a kernel extension to actually function.  In this case you have to wait until Mad Katz release a compatible upgrade... or you might want to disable the extra protection and reinstate the kernel extension.

Answer (score -1):

You asked for a workaround and I am giving you a WORKING workaround

1. Uninstall Mad Catz Editor
2. Install USB Drive (I am not sure if this step is optional)
3. Disable everything in USB Drive
4. Click on Status, see Mad Catz R.A.T.9 Wireless Mouse in the list of currently handled by the USB Overdrive window
5. Launch Controller Mate. See how you can know remap the wheel (favorite thing about the mouse!) to anything you want.

I have the wheel remapped to zoom in/out, and the side buttons to Volume Up/Down

Comment: What is "UBS Drive" which needs to be installed in step 2? And I don't think the step can be optional if you proceed to disable everything in it in the next step

Comment: I think he would like to say "USB Overdrive", a device driver (+ software) which handles USB controlers (mouse, keyboard, etc.)