# Mad Catz RAT 3 Mouse Drivers/Software

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, mouse, driver

Does anyone happen to know where I can get the RAT3 drivers?
I have a 2015 MBP.

Currently my Mac will not do any hovering of the mouse and I think it may be due to the lack of drivers for the mouse.

The Mad Catz site does not have any downloads anymore.

Comment: related - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209682/el-capitan-incompatible-with-mad-catz-editor?

Answer (score 1):

I have a Mad Catz RAT MMO7 mouse and it works fine without any drivers with OS X 10.11 as a regular mouse. None of the key programming, etc. will work without the Mac drivers and nothing is available or supported.

The company went bankrupt several years ago and closed down, but they have just recently restarted, so new stuff may be coming out as they update their web site.